# Eclipse 3 SWT plugin context menu item visibility

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, contextmenu

I develop an Eclipse 3 plugin and I would like to set context menu item visibility from code.

My menuContribution parentID is #CompilationUnitEditorContext.

When I try to find HandledMenuItem by id with "ModelService.findElements" method, it cannot find it. I tried to find it in every way.

My Fragment.e4xmi:

```
<elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_htd08JlQEeexy-nXp72DpA" elementId="my-plugin.menucontribution.context" positionInParent="before=additions" parentId="#CompilationUnitEditorContext">
  <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_lQM74JlQEeexy-nXp72DpA" elementId="my-plugin.handledmenuitem.contextmenuitem" label="Do something" command="_Rj_3AJlQEeexy-nXp72DpA"/>
</elements>
```

Comment: This appears to be Eclipse 4 (e4) **not** Eclipse 3.

Comment: Unfortunately we switched back to Eclipse 3 , because of incompatibility problems.

Comment: By the way I was able to get HandledMenuItem from it's contributor: contextVariables.getApplication().getMenuContributions().getChildren().get(0)   ,but It still visible in context menu. Should I refresh the UI or something?

Comment: setToBeRendered() solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Get MenuItem with contextVariables.getApplication().getMenuContributions().get‌​Children().get(0) , then use setToBeRendered().